# How can I create it so that it can do 2 new lines and then the main message between the new lines?

Tags: java, json

**`"broadcastMessage": "\n\u2717 \u00A74%player%\u00264 was kicked by AntiCheat for cheating.\n"`**
This is JSON ( config for a Minecraft anticheat ), but apparently when using the \n at the start and end only makes one new line, and not two.
I want it so that it makes 2 new lines, then it broadcasts that message in between the new lines.
Hopefully, I'm explaining enough.

Comment: To clarify, you want an empty line between messages, correct?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/50j7Lxa.png I want to have it so that empty line is also below the broadcast message, there is already one on top, and I want to have another one at bottom. Pretty much inbetween the broadcast message.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Minecraft modding or if messages are automatically padded, but have you tried adding another \n at the end of your message?

Comment: I have, and it is the same result as the image shown.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the interface you're using. You might want to ask on a Minecraft-specific forum, since this issue probably depends on how the messaging system in Minecraft works.

Comment: Yea, by just googling the system, apparently \n makes an extra line according to https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Formatting_codes but i'm still unsure as to why that wouldn't work in the start and end of the message.

Comment: It makes a new line at the top and not the bottom?

Comment: sorry for late reply, but yeah, it only makes one at top, but not at bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way I used to do this was either having a space at the end or some color-code which won't be visible since there is no letter following. This means something like this:

`\n %player% has been kicked [...] \n $c$l`

However, you can also just send an empty second message, thus having a new empty line. You could also try some invisible characters, or check if another line break will have the desired outcome (I think I remember that only the last one will be ignored)

Let me know which solution worked for you!